# Odd Safari behavior with respect to transitions/animations

Tags: ios, css, safari

I have a really odd bug in Safari 8 + 9 on desktop and on iOS 8.4 and higher on mobile and cannot really understand why it is happening or how to fix it. I can reproduce it with 100% accuracy.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to http://demo.phppointofsalestaging.com and hit login
2. Click the 3 horizontal bars to collapse and expand the menu. Try this a few times to verify it is hiding/showing menu.
3. Click Items module. Again click the 3 horizontal bars to collapse and expand the menu. Try this a few times to verify it is hiding/showing menu.
4. Edit an existing item. Go to bottom and hit submit. You will then be transferred back to they items list. Again click the 3 horizontal bars and you will see that the text disappears and appears to break.

The only way to fix this is to empty cache.

See video for walkthrough of bug:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/on8v7803alkrz12/odd_safari_behavior_animations.mov?dl=0

**The only way I know how to fix this with code is to remove all css animations and transitions.**

EDIT:

I removed the following and it now works...I just want to know why.

assets/css/style.css

```
 .rollover {
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
   position: relative;
   background-color: black;
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 30px;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
---REMOVED--  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
}
.rollover:after {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  /*-webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);*/
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that there was a css transition was happening and was NOT finishing before the next page loaded. (A link caused an transition but also caused the browser to go to next page).

This somehow ruined the cache for Safari and caused all these issues. The solution is to remove the transaction OR fix the logic with the css transition.